# How do I get ticks since epoch in dart?

Tags: dart

I found the `millisecondsSinceEpoch` in `Datetime` in dart lang, but my request need the tick since Epoch. So how can I convert `DateTime.now()` to ticks since Epoch?

Comment: What do you mean by "tick"? Seconds?

Comment: For example: 637310562843838745 -> 2020-07-22​T23:11:24.383Z. I use https://tickstodatetime.azurewebsites.net/. Now I need convert the DateTime.now to ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ticks` are apparently defined in .NET as:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond (see TicksPerMillisecond) and 10 million ticks in a second.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar, which represents MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Ticks

In the webpage linked as example in this question (https://tickstodatetime.azurewebsites.net/) we can see that JavaScript does not understand ticks and therefore the webpage are converting the ticks into milliseconds since epoch.

I have therefore reversed this and make the following example:

```
void main() {
  print(DateTime.now().ticks); // 637318676156933690
}

const _epochTicks = 621355968000000000;
extension TicksOnDateTime on DateTime {
  int get ticks => this.microsecondsSinceEpoch * 10 + _epochTicks;
}
```

Comment: I had this idea before getting confused by Iso8601String. Since its multiplied by `10` it's not actually ticks for `DateTime.now()`, although there's only a very small error. For eg, if only `daysSinceEpoch` was present, then `(daysSinceEpoch * 24 * 3600 * 1000) * 10 + _epochTicks` would be the ticks for the beginning of the day and not now. However, this might be the only way to get it using the core library with the least error.